# paypal sandbox refund issue in core php

Tags: php, paypal-sandbox

i trying to call paypal refund api also passes correct arguments required data that is transaction id but always get error as follows

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2017-12-21T06:48:53Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 83994511980f5
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 94.0
    [BUILD] => 40680762
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10009
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => You can not refund this type of transaction
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    [REFUNDSTATUS] => None
    [PENDINGREASON] => None
)
```

Comment: Please help me out from this issue ASAP i thanks in advance.

Comment: [May be helpful](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/563)  Or [this one](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/914)

Comment: Hi @Anant i tried things by referring the link but no luck still having same issue